# How can i invoke a paper scanner using php code?

Tags: php, scanning, twain

How can I invoke a paper scanner using php code?

I have already used Dynamic Web TWAIN for scanning, but it is not free.

I need an open source code to scan.

Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a server side language and cannot interact with client side hardware. You can use a web-based TWAIN SDK to scan documents in your PHP app. Check out this article which might help: http://www.dynamsoft.com/blog/document-imaging/how-to-scan-documents-in-php

You can also use Scanner.js: https://github.com/Asprise/scannerjs.javascript-scanner-access-in-browsers-chrome-ie.scanner.js

Maybe you can try phpSANE: https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpsane/

> phpSANE is a web-based frontend for SANE written in HTML/PHP so you
>   can scan with your web-browser. It also supports OCR.

PHP Printer library: https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php

Comment: Yes, this is open source: https://github.com/Asprise/scannerjs.javascript-scanner-access-in-browsers-chrome-ie.scanner.js

Comment: scanner.js is not open source

Comment: I added a new library example in my answer. Please detail what you want to print. You have some pdf/txt file that you want to print directly from PHP? You want the PHP to send a command to the printer?

Comment: I want the PHP to send a command to invoke the scanner for scanning papers.

Comment: How can i use phpSANE in windows system.?

Comment: The question that you are actually asking is how to run PHP on windows. Because phpSANE is just a PHP script. You should use IIS or XAMP/MAMP. You can find a tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6ENnaRotmo that explains how to install PHP, Apache and MySql on windows. By the way, latest PHP version is 7.2, I suggest you to use that version. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar position as you and found there were 0 open-source libraries.

Thus, I created a library https://github.com/spacemudd/webagent-scanner.

What you need to do:

- Install Python 2.7.
- Navigate to webagent-scanner's root folder and run: `python setup.py py2exe`
- In dist/ and open `app.exe`. This will create a localhost web server w/ port 8087.
- In your web application, ensure the user has app.exe running.
- Use Javascript to make a GET request to https://localhost:8087/scan
- The response of the GET request... you inject it in a form to send it to your PHP backend.